# what is right algorithm and data structure for a user defined collection with specific insertion and deletion

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

This question is asked in one of investment banking company's interview .
I have to design myCache which keeps a cache of studentRecords object and can have one object of myCache of studentRecords collection.When user wants to insert record in studentRecords it will only insert record if there is less than 20 record in collection .otherwise it will remove the least used record from the studentRecords and insert the record.Record will be inserted on basis of ranking of studentRecords in sorted order.When user wants to read the record it will check if studentRecords exist in myCache ,if not exist then will read record from studentRecords collection.

I  created a  doubly linked list and insert the record on basis of ranking .also can make a mycache class which is singleton and reads records from cache .But how to delete records which are least used .

I can create a array list which delete records top in array(least used record) but can not keep elements on basis of ordering of rank. and to read record on basis of ranking is expensive again .

Is there any other solution which would have  impressed interviewer.

myCache class have functions like :

```
        public void removeRecordFromStudentRecords(String rank); 
        public void addRecordToStudentRecords(StudentRecords st); 
        public Student readRecordFromStudentRecords(String rank);
```

table of StudentRecords

SrNo rank name maths science total percentage
1 1 rohan 90 90 180 90
2 2 sohan 80 90 160 80
3 3 abhi 70 70 140 70

Comment: "and can have one object of myCache of studentRecords collection." what can have one object of myCache?

Comment: myCache class have functions like : 
public void removeRecordFromStudentRecords(String rank);     
public void addRecordToStudentRecords(StudentRecords st);
public Student readRecordFromStudentRecords(String rank);

it should not have more than one object of studentRecords collection

Comment: Could you please update your question with this code. Code don't belong into comments. Some examples of your solution would be also nice. :)

Comment: Do you want to discard the least used (i.e. record that's been accessed the fewest times), or the least *recently* used (i.e. the record that was accessed before any of the other records in the cache)?

Comment: @JimMischel :record that's been accessed the fewest times

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about a Cache we should optimize time complexity first and memory later.

So, in this case, I can provide next solution:

- Use `Map` (i.e. HashMap) for storing records (`key: recordId, value: Record`).
- Use `Stack` for last used items (`value: recordId`).
- Use `Tree` (i.e. BST) for holding rank (`key: rankValue, value: recordId`).

Combination of this tree data structures allows to provide the fastest solution (I guess).

- Read by Id operation: O(1) - just simple get from the map
- Add record operation: O(ln N) - because we need to insert key into tree (we do not include balancing into counting complaxity)
- Remove by rank operation: O(ln N) - simply finding recordId by rank in Tree( don't forget removing record from Map and recordID from Stack)

This is just brief overview of the problem. Guess, it's enough info to understand the main idea.

Comment: Thanks for nice solution , just one problem  "Use Stack for last used items" I don't need last used , need least used item .

Comment: Need one more suggestion,it was mentioned in the question to use user defined collection .I really don't understand what it means . should I used collections defined in Java or interviewer wants me to implement new collections ?

Comment: Oh, my fault. "least used" problem might be solved almost the same way as the last used. just use `Queue` instead of `Stack`.
What about "user defined collections" - guess, they wanted you to implement your own solution. It's not so hard, but needs some additional knowledge

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep a track of the least used record, you need to store the number of hits each record has (if you do not know what "hits" are, I suggest you look up "hits and misses in caching") So each studentRecord can be an object of a class as follows:

```
class StudentRecord{
    int unique_id;
    int ranking;
    int hits
}
StudentRecord studentRecord = new StudentRecord();
```

sort your cache based on studentRecord.ranking and when you need to decide which studentRecord to delete, simply traverse the cache on the basis of hits and delete the element with the minimum hits.

To maintain hits, whenever you get a query for a studentRecord based on its unique_id, you increment its hits by 1. Thus, hits will give you a metric of which studentRecord is most used/least used

**EDIT:** Your question is now much clearer. For sorting, you can use simple insertion sort. The reasons for this are 1) you have max 20 elements in your cache and 2) when you try and insert a new element, insertion sort will help you perfectly to find the index where you can place the element. In fact, technically speaking, you need only sort once. Then you just need to figure out where to insert future elements.

I would say a simple linked list with arbitrary access (like java.util.ArrayList) will suffice. It will give you random access as in arrays and also the provision to accomodate less than 20 elements. I see no reason to make a doubly linked list since there is no need to access an element's left and right neighbours here...

Comment: Can you explain what data structure is useful in this scenario and how to keep data sorted in the collection .

Answer (score -1):

Least Recently Used Scheduling technique can be applied here,you can keep a byte field for each entry in your list.

So everytime an entry of your object is used you can push 1 to the byte(b>>1).

So for entries which are being more frequently used, you'll have a lot of 1s in the binary representation for your byte.

For data, not being used at all will have all 0s.

And everytime, you are required to delete an entry from your cache, just delete the one with 0 or the one with the smallest value of this byte field.

Also, to remember references for greater time spans than just eight, you can use bigger datatypes.